# Configure the poller in Spring Integration as queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, poller

I'm working at implementing a buffer, in order to execute various jobs. 
I'm working on a Spring-based project. 
I decided to use Spring Integration to accomplish my aim. I went through a Cafè sample project in order to understand how SI works.

To demonstrate Spring Integration I implemented a table where I dynamically insert jobs to be executed. 
This table is the "gateway". Then I configured a router and various channels.

What I don't fully understand are the poller elements which have to check if new jobs in the "gateway" are present.
Is this correct?

If so, how can I configure the poller?
Thanks in advance! 
Here the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">


<int:gateway id="usersToSend" service-interface="it.stasbranger.spidly.rss.UsersToSend" />


<int:channel id="channel" />

<int:channel id="providers"/>
<int:router input-channel="providers" ref="providerRouter" method="resolveProviderChannel"/>

<int:channel id="twitterChannel">
      <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="twitterChannel" ref="twitterService" method="updateStatusByProfile"/>

<int:channel id="facebookChannel">
      <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="facebookChannel" ref="facebookService" method="updateStatusByProfile"/>

<int:channel id="linkedinChannel">
      <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="linkedinChannel" ref="linkedinService" method="writeSlogan2Linkedin"/>

<bean id="twitterService" class="it.social.TwitterService"/>
<bean id="facebookService" class="it.social.FacebookService"/>
<bean id="linkedinService" class="it.social.LinkedinService"/>

<int:poller id="poller" default="true">

</int:poller>
```

FB

Answer (score 2):

`<gateway/>`s are not polled, they are "message-driven" in that the caller "sends" a message into the flow using the gateway.

For a polling scenario, use an `<int:inbound-channel-adapter/>` which polls a method (on the poller's schedule) looking for work to do.

If the method returns null, the poller goes back to sleep (until the next trigger). If the method returns a value, the message is sent to the channel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 
I configured as you said an inbound channel adapter, linking it to the  channel input and a method which returns me a Message object or null.
I don't accomplish to implment the poller. 
If I insert in the channel adapter tag the "int-poller" element, I get an error, because no poller is defined. How can I work this out?
One more thing: in the poller element I set "fixed-rate property", but it's underlined in red, because it's not allowed for that position. Ideas?

Comment: If you don't add a `<poller/>` as a child element of the `<inbound-channel-adapter/>` it will use the default poller you have defined. The error is probably because your IDE has cached the wrong version of the schema. If you are using STS, many of those problems have been fixed in recent versions; if you are using an older version, there are some suggestions here... http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126494-Avoiding-STS-Bogus-Warnings-And-Errors